# How to use a different partition to store Restore Points in Windows?

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, system-restore

I'm running Windows 7, and it's installed on a 32 GB partition which is currently running low on space (and expanding it is not an option). Windows System Restore takes up several Gigs of that space. Since I like having many restore points available, I don't want to decrease the amount of space available for system restore. So my option is to try and get Windows to save my Restore Points on a different partition. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about 7, but I know this was not possible in Vista.  The system restore file, by definition in the OS, must reside on the system drive.  So you're most likely going to have to clear out some restore points or perhaps find other things on that drive you can move, like your Users folder.

Comment: Do you know where that file is? Would it be possible to move it, and then place a hard link?

Comment: Its the hidden folder called "System Volume Information"